# How Can I Debug Ruby 2.0+ Scripts in Emacs?

Tags: ruby, emacs

I've found some information on how to setup debugging inside of emacs for ruby 1.9.3 and below, but I can't find anything for ruby 2.0 or higher.  How can I debug ruby 2.0 and higher scripts in emacs?

Comment: Have you tried just using the 1.9.3 setup with 2.0? Afaik, (and I don't really use ruby), there's not a huge change between ruby 1.9  & ruby 2

Comment: The old ruby-debug package that emacs was using doesn't support ruby 2 and higher.  I know bye-bug works with new versions of ruby, but I'm not sure about emacs

Comment: same issue here, have you found any solutions?? I am looking into https://github.com/realgud/realgud but not sure yet

Comment: I just used intellij instead of Emacs.